# problem using ggplot2::stat_summary with units in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, units-of-measurement

I receive an error when using stat_summary on values with defined units. The code works fine on unitless data. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(units)

tb <- tibble(a=1:8 %>% set_units(kg),b=1:8) 
tb_unitless <- drop_units(tb)
```

now creating a plot with a mean line works fine on the tibble without units:

```
ggplot(tb_unitless,aes(x=b,y=a)) + 
stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom="hline",aes(yintercept=after_stat(y)))
```

but for some reason does not work on the tibble with units:

```
ggplot(tb,aes(x=b,y=a)) + 
stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom="hline",aes(yintercept=after_stat(y)))
```

returns:

```
Error in `stat_summary()`:
! Problem while mapping stat to aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'drop_units' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

If I remember well, this did work in the past -- is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not sure why, but this appears to be specific to `geom_hline`? E.g. `ggplot(tb,aes(x=b,y=a)) + 
  stat_summary(aes(color = after_stat(y)), fun = "mean", geom = "point")` works fine.

Comment: This is unusual looking, but does work: `ggplot(tb,aes(x=b,y=a)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom="hline",aes(yintercept=after_stat(y %>% set_units(kg)), x = mean(.data[['b']])))`

Comment: The `hline` geom doesn't have an x aesthetic

Comment: @Seth Although your solutions works, it requires prior knowledge of the units a is in.